# Does intermediate extension functor commutes with forgetful functor in equivariant derived category?

Tags: derived-categories, perverse-sheaves, equivariant, intersection-cohomology

The forgetful functor from $D^b_G(X)$ to $D^b(X)$ carries $Perv_G(X)$ to $Perv(X)$ by definition $5.1$ in the book of Bernstein and Lunts. My question is do the following functors, intermediate extension, kernel and cokernel commute with forgetful functor?

Comment: I don’t think so, since intersection homology and equivariant intersection homology are different, see the part of Bernstein and Lunts where they discuss intersection homology of toric varieties.